# Using field as row in django tables

Tags: django

I'm using the django_tables2 library and I don't see anywhere in the documentation to use the fields as rows instead of columns.

```
class PizzaTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaInstance
        fields = ("pizza", "type", "size", "price")
        attrs = {"class": "mytable"}
```

trying to display two instances under one row like so:

```
         small    large
cheese   $1       $2

instead of 
cheese small $1
cheese large $2
```

Can I use pizza and type as rows in django_tables2 library?

Comment: this is probably bad idea, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to sort two instances of my pizza in one row only displaying their unique values such as size and price while sharing the pizza type.